# React Native: Backend retrieves 'undefined' when uploading images

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, nestjs, file-handling

I try to upload images to my backend server, but I'm doing something wrong the api call.

Used Packages...

```
"react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
"form-data": "^4.0.0",
"axios": "^0.21.4",
"react-native": "0.67.3"
...
..
.
```

Where I pick the Images from the Gallery:

```
import {
  launchImageLibrary,
} from 'react-native-image-picker';
import {uploadProfileImages} from '../services/apiService';

export function MyRNApp() {
let image1: any,
    image2: any,
    image3: any,
    image4: any,
    image5: any = null;

launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
              if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
              } else if (response.errorCode) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.errorCode);
              } else if (response.assets) {
                  image1 = {
                    uri: response.assets[0].uri,
                    type: response.assets[0].type,
                    name: response.assets[0].fileName,
                  };
                  
                  image2 = {
                    uri: response.assets[1].uri,
                    type: response.assets[1].type,
                    name: response.assets[1].fileName,
                  };
                
                  image3 = {
                    uri: response.assets[2].uri,
                    type: response.assets[2].type,
                    name: response.assets[2].fileName,
                  };
                  image4 = {
                    uri: response.assets[3].uri,
                    type: response.assets[3].type,
                    name: response.assets[3].fileName,
                  };
                  image5 = {
                    uri: response.assets[4].uri,
                    type: response.assets[4].type,
                    name: response.assets[4].fileName,
                  };
              }
            });
const registerComplete = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log('Before upload: ' + image1);
      await uploadProfileImages(image1, image2, image3, image4, image5)
        .then(async res => {
          console.log('images uploaded...');
          console.log('Result: ', res);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
  };

}
```

My actuall axios call:

```
import FormData from 'form-data';

export async function uploadProfileImages(
  image1: any,
  image2: any,
  image3: any,
  image4: any,
  image5: any,
): Promise<any> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('images', image1);
  formData.append('images', image2);
  formData.append('images', image3);
  formData.append('images', image4);
  formData.append('images', image5);
  return await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${API_URL}upload`,
    data: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      Authorization: AUTH_HEADER,
    },
  });
}
```

NestJs Backend:

```
@Post('upload')
  @HttpCode(200)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FilesInterceptor('images', 5, {
      dest: '../uploads',
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
          cb(null, true);
        } else {
          cb(new Error('No supported filetype'), false);
        }
      },
    }),
  )
  async uploadFile(
    @UploadedFiles() images: Array<Express.Multer.File>,
    @Request() req: any,
  ): Promise<any> {
    if (req.headers['authorization'] === process.env.UPLOAD_KEY) {
      >there it says 'undefined' when making call from RN App 
      console.log('Uploaded files: ' + images[0]);
      return { files: images };
    } else {
      return { status: 'failed' };
    }
  }
```

The Backend API works fine (Tested in Postman).
But when I'm making the api call in the RN App, it seems like the actuall photo data will not be send.

Comment: `response.assets[0].uri` return local file cache reference not actually file data. You need to fetch data either as base64 or BLOB format

Comment: It didn't work out either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a another solution and that **works for me**:

Where I pick the Image from the Gallery:

```
export function RNScreen(){
let photo = {
    uri: '',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'image.jpg',
  };
launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
              if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
              } else if (response.errorCode) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.errorCode);
              } else if (response.assets) {
                photo.uri =
                  Platform.OS === 'android'
                    ? String(response.assets[0].uri)
                    : String(response.assets[0].uri).replace('file://', '');
              }
            });
}
```

Upload Progress:

```
let data = new FormData();
      data.append('images', photo);

      let config = {
        Authorization: AUTH_HEADER,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      };
      axios.post(API_URL + 'upload', data, {headers: config}).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
```